# mysql - How to save ñ

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding

Whenever I try to save `ñ` it becomes `?` in the mysql database. After some few readings it is suggested that I have to change my jsp charset to `UTF-8`. For some reasons I have to stick to `ISO-8859-1`. My database table encoding is `latin1`. How can I fix this? Please help.

Comment: Change your table encoding to UTF

Comment: When you retrieve the value is still `?` or it prints as `ñ`? It can be a charset problem of the program you are using to view the database, but not a problem for your application.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós When I check my database table it displays ?

Comment: What operating system is MySQL installed upon?

Comment: Please post the relevant jsp and follow the steps I described in my answer

Answer (score 6):

Go to your database administration with `MySQL WorkBench` for example, put the Engine to `InnoDB` and the collation to `utf8-utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 5):

You state in your question that you require a ISO-8859-1 backend (latin1), and a Unicode (UTF-8) frontend. This setup is crazy, because the set on the frontend is much larger than that allowed in the database. The *sanest* thing would be using the same encoding through the software stack, but also using Unicode only for storage would make sense.

As you should know, a String is a human concept for a sequence of characters. In computer programs, a String is **not** that: it can be *viewed* as a sequence of characters, but it's really a pair data structure: **a stream of bytes and an encoding**.

Once you understand that passing a String is really passing bytes and a scheme, let's see who sends what:

1. Browser to HTTP server (usually same encoding as the form page, so UTF-8. The scheme is specified via `Content-Type`. If missing, the server will pick one based on [its own strategy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html), for example default to ISO-8859-1 or a configuration parameter)
2. HTTP Server to Java program (it's Java to Java, so the encoding doesn't matter since we pass String objects)
3. Java client to MySQL server (the [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html) documentation is quite convoluted - it uses the `character_set_server` system variable, possibly overridden by the `characterEncoding` connection parameter)

To understand where the problem lies, first assure that the column is really stored as latin1:

```
SELECT character_set_name, collation_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = :DATABASE
        AND table_name = :TABLE
        AND column_name = :COLUMN;
```

Then write the Java string you get from the request to a log file:

```
logger.info(request.getParameter("word"));
```

And finally see what actually is in the column:

```
SELECT HEX(:column) FROM :table
```

At this point you'll have enough information to understand the problem. If it's really a question mark (and not a [replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29)) likely it's MySQL trying to transcode a character from a larger set (let's say Unicode) to a narrower one which doesn't contain it. The strange thing here is that [ñ belongs to both](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm) ISO-8859-1 (0xF1, decimal 241) and Unicode (U+00F1), so it'd seem like there's a third charset (maybe a codepage?) involved in the round trip.

More information may help (operating system, HTTP server, MySQL version)

Comment: How comes that I can manually save ñ letter on a latin1 field, but after I convert it to binary the conversion to utf8_general_ci fails because of an "unknown string" error 1366? I can view it perfectly as ñ when saved in the table, but conversion to binary and then utf8 fails.

Answer (score 4):

Change your db table content encoding to UTF-8

Here's the command for whole DB conversion

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And this is for single tables conversion

```
ALTER TABLE db_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue, I have the same situation.

Answer (score 3):

change your table collate to `utf8_spanish_ci`

where `ñ` is not equal to `n` but if you want both characters to be equal use

`utf8_general_ci` instead

Comment: OP question was not actually what I was looking for, I had a problem where char Ñ was being saved as N, it was because my tables where using collate utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 1):

I try several combinations, but this works for me:

VARCHAR(255) BINARY CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin

When data retrieve in dbforge express, shows like:
NIÃ‘A

but in the application shows like:
NIÑA

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. Found out that is not an issue about encoding UTF-8 or whatever charset. I imported my data from windows ANSI and all my Ñ and ñ where put in the database perfectly as it should be. Example last names showed on database **last_name = "MUÑOZ"**. I was able to select normally from the database with query **Select * from database where last_name  LIKE "%muñoz%"** and phpmyadmin show me results fine. It selected all "MUÑOZ" and "MUNOZ" without a problem. So phpmyadmin does show all my Ñ and ñ **without any problems**.

The problem was the program itself. All my characters mention, showed as you describe with the funky **"MU�OZ" question mark**. I had follow all advice everywhere. Set my headers correctly and tried all my charsets available. Even used google fonts and whatsoever font available to display correctly those last names, but no success.

Then I remembered an old program that was able to do the trick back and forth transparently and peeked into the code to figure it out: The database itself, showing all my special characters was the problem. Remember, I uploaded using windows ANSI encoding. Phpmyadmin did as expected, uploaded all as instructed.

The old program fixed this problem **translating the Ñ to its UNICODE HTML Entity: `&#209;`** (see chart here https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00D1 ) a process done back and forth from MySQL to the app.

So you just need to change your database strings containing the letter Ñ and ñ to their corresponding UNICODE to reflect correctly on your browser with UTF charset.

In my case, I solved my issues replacing all my Ñ and ñ for their corresponding UNICODE in all the last names in my database.

```
UPDATE database_name
SET 
    last_name = REPLACE(last_name,
        'MUÑOZ',
        'MU&#209;OZ');
```

Now, Im able to display, browse, even search all my correct last names and accents/tildes, proper to spanish language. I hope this helps. It was a pain to figure it out, but an old program solved the problem. Best regards and happy coding !

Comment: That would not solve the problem when data is inserted again. Or do you propose to replace characters every time someone saves data to the database? That's untenable... It is, indeed, an encoding problem, see the other answers, and your own answer. You fixed it in your case by.. using the proper encoding.

Comment: Well its solved permanently on goverment databases in south america. We have that issue and thats how we solved it here. using their UNICODE HTML Entity. We can insert, delete, update, and all functions of MySQL. No problem, the program does it transparently.

Comment: Oh, have no worries, I've seen people use HTML entities instead of fixing encoding plenty of time. It can probably even work, for a while. But then someone comes with another special character and then what, you redo all this with the new special character? Add more exceptions everywhere to account for all edge cases? That's what I mean by "untenable"; it's not a long term viable solution, it requires maintenance. Fixing the correct encoding, would solve the problem, without the need to fix it again every now and then.

Comment: I dont create the exceptions, the program does it automatically with our limited set of funki characters. they are not many, á, é, í, ó, ú their capitals, ñ and Ñ are the problem ones. Very seldom dieresis are used ü, Ü.  Thats all translations needed for our last names database. :)