# Ñ and possibly other special character being truncated MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to populate a table on my database with some rows containing some latin characters specifically "Ñ". This list is from an excel where I convert to a csv file.

My CSV file has contents like these:

```
"1619","137601000","CITY OF LAS PIÑAS","METRO MANILA","NCR","National Capital Region","MM"
"1620","137602000","CITY OF MAKATI","METRO MANILA","NCR","National Capital Region","MM"
"1627","137604000","CITY OF PARAÑAQUE","METRO MANILA","NCR","National Capital Region","MM"
```

I load this list to my target table with the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/my/path/to/file.csv' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I've also tried adding the CHARACTER SET to my load statement, but I've got same result:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/my/path/to/file.csv' INTO TABLE mytable CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But after loading, when I checked on the content of my table, fields that contains "Ñ" are being truncated.

```
| 1619 | 137601000 | CITY OF LAS PI                                 | METRO MANILA              | NCR    | National Capital Region              | MM   |
| 1620 | 137602000 | CITY OF MAKATI                                 | METRO MANILA              | NCR    | National Capital Region              | MM   |
| 1627 | 137604000 | CITY OF PARA                                   | METRO MANILA              | NCR    | National Capital Region              | MM   |
```

Tried some of the suggestion on [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489508/mysql-how-to-save-%C3%B1) but still to no avail.

I tried to extract the content of the table as it may only be a representation problem, but field with "Ñ" were really truncated.

Below are helpful infos that may help in resolving this issue.

I created my database with with this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE myDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

and my table with this:

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`code` int(11) NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`province` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`region` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`regionname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`area` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**OS Variant and Version**

```
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

**MySQL Variant and Version**

- mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

**Table column character setup**

```
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| column_name | character_set_name | collation_name  |
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| id          | NULL               | NULL            |
| code        | NULL               | NULL            |
| city        | utf8               | utf8_unicode_ci |
| province    | utf8               | utf8_unicode_ci |
| region      | utf8               | utf8_unicode_ci |
| regionname  | utf8               | utf8_unicode_ci |
| area        | utf8               | utf8_unicode_ci |
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

**My Database setup**

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database    | Create Database                                                                              |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| myDbName    | CREATE DATABASE `myDbName` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci */    |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: can you recreate on sqlfiddle?

Comment: How do i replicate batch loading in sqlfiddle? where do i put the file?

Comment: :( I tried on my MariaDB, using load data, didn't recreate it.

Comment: @Dylan Su, I tried to insert one entry on sqlfiddle with the "Ñ" and when I try to query it back, it did not truncate the field.. So what do you think?

Comment: I have no idea at all

Comment: What are the character set settings for the session you're running this in? `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'` ...

Answer (score 0):

Truncation is usually caused by

- The client had accented characters encoded in latin1, and
- `SET NAMES utf8` was in effect during the `INSERT` (or `LOAD DATA` in your case)

That is, the csv file is not really in utf8 format.  Try some other `CHARACTER SET` in the `LOAD DATA`, probably `latin1`.